# Standard method names, why is the l in println not capital?

Tags: java, standards, convention

I've been programming in Java for 6 weeks now, and was wondering why in println the l is lower case, but in most other methods each word starts with an upper case letter.

Is this because line is abreviated? Are there a set of standards that I should be aware of when naming methods. I've had a look through the Sun standards, and can't see a rule anywhere about making the first letter of an abrivated word lower case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `println` existed way before Java

Comment: Kind of a non-answer. What language?

Comment: Not sure if any language had `println` first, but the form of the name was clearly influenced by Pascal's `writeln`.  

It is an admitted oddity.

Comment: Interesting reading: http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages/Strng.html#StrngSmplPrnt

Comment: Println has been in the C I/O libraries since forever ...

Answer (score 2):

There's many other more jarring inconsistencies if you look hard enough.  The naming standard suggests that there should never be runs of capitals, even in abbreviations.  `Uri`, `Url`, `UrlConnection`, `HttpClient` are the expected names of cases.

Unfortunately, changing them is unlikely to be worth the effort?

Comment: Similarly, if you take any language, the most irregular verbs are often the oldest words in the language. For instance how about Spanish's verb, ser, to be.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Very insightful comment